# Jquery multiple search on a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and would like to have a way that you can search multiple row at the same time.

e.g. Putting something into box number as well as in the deception.

This is my HTML.

```
<table id="main-table">
<tbody>
    <tr class="inputs open">
        <th><input type="text" name="box_number"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="make"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="qty"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="deception"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>N57</td>
        <td>N/a</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>N23</td>
        <td>N/a</td>
        <td>8d</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my JS

```
$(document).on('change keyup click touchstart', ".inputs input", function (event) {
var inputs = $(".inputs input");
    $.each(inputs, function() {
        //Get the index
        var inputIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();
        //Getting the input val
        var inputVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        //Getting all tr other then add new
        var $trList = $(this).parent().parent().siblings().not(".add_new_item");
        //Each tr list
        $.each($trList, function() {
            //Getting each td from the td   
            var $td = $($trList).children().eq(inputIndex);
            if (($td.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal) > -1) || inputVal.length < 1) { //Check if the search term is in the td text
                //$(this).removeClass("hide");
            } else {
                if ($(this).hasClass('first-item')) {

                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("hide");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple text boxes you can use single text box & check for its values in the tables td tag.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table id="main-table">
            <input type="text" id="box_number">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>N57</td>
                <td>N/a</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>N23</td>
                <td>N/a</td>
                <td>8d</td>
                <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('change keyup click touchstart', "#box_number", function (event) {
                var input = $("#box_number").val();
                    $("tr").each(function(i){
                        $(this).hide();
                    });
                    $("tr").find("td").each(function(data){
                        var v = $(this);                        
                        if(v.text().includes(input))                        
                        v.closest("tr").show();

                    });

                   });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will not work, As I would like to be able to search multiple at the same time. Like search row one for something and then row two for something else.